# Gamelin, VIII.6 Exercise #3

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)$ be analytic on an open set containing a closed path $\gamma$, and suppose $f(z) \not= 0$ on $\gamma$. Show that the increase in $\arg f(z)$ around $\gamma$ is $2\pi W(f \circ \gamma,0)$.

My attempted work:

Suppose $f(z) \not= 0$ on $\gamma$, We want to show,

$$\int_\gamma d(\arg(f(z))=2\pi  W(f \circ \gamma,0)$$
or equivalently,

$$W(f \circ \gamma,0)=\frac 1{2\pi} \int_\gamma d(\arg(f(z))$$ we have

\begin{align*}
\frac 1{2\pi} \int_\gamma d(\arg z)=W(\gamma,0)=\int_\gamma d(\log z)=\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac 1{z}\,dz=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{z'}{z}\, dz
\end{align*}
apply $f$ to above we get, 
\begin{align*}
 \frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{f \circ \gamma} \frac {f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz=\frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{f \circ \gamma }d(\log f(z))= \frac 1{2\pi} \int_{f \circ \gamma} d(\arg f(z))=W(f \circ \gamma,0)
\end{align*}
Then we get,

$$\frac 1{2\pi} \int_\gamma d(\arg z)=W(\gamma,0)=\frac 1{2\pi} \int_{f \circ \gamma} d(\arg f(z))=W(f \circ \gamma,0)$$

Comment: What is $W(f\circ\gamma,0)$?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis In general, $W(\gamma, 0)$ is the **winding number** of the path $\gamma$ around $z_0$, which is defined in page 242 of the Gamelin textbook to "be the increase in the argument of $z-z_0$ around $\gamma$, normalized by dividing by $2\pi$". (By the way, the OP and I are working together on this problem and we both got stuck.)

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis I mean $W(\gamma,z_0)$.